# What is wrong with php file? Fatal error in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I found out that my `error_log` file was about 3 GB. I deleted it, installed a plugin called Error Log Monitor and this is the error I get a few times a day:

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart_subtotal() on null in /home/blabla/www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php on line 77`

This is the code from line 73-81:

```
function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <?php /* translators: %d: number of items in cart */ ?>
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ); ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your theme and woocommerce plugin running on the last version? Do you use a cache plugin?

Comment: Everything is up to date

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using the Storefront theme, in which cause I would first do the following:

Is Wordpress up to date?
Is Woocommerce Up to date?
Is the theme up to date?

If yes go to the next steps:
Switch to one of the WP themes that came with the theme. Is error gone?
Disable all plugins. Then enable them one by one and check for the error.

This should help you isolate the issue.